# How do I define a secondary y-axis with variable relation to the primary y-axis?

Tags: python, function, axis

I want to define a secondary y-axis where the scale is variable and a function of an input array (that is relative to the primary y-axis):

```
def my_func(x):
    print(x)
    if x.any() < 4.0:
        return x*0.4
    else:
        return x*0.8
def my_inverse_func(x):
    return x/0.4

axy = ax[0].secondary_yaxis('right', functions= (my_func, my_inverse_func))
```

That doesn't seem to work though, as the run shows that `x = [-1.e-03  1.e+01]` although the primary y-axis has several, only positive values. As a consequence, only the first condition is satisfied (`x<4.0`) and the secondary y-axis scale is not variable. What am I missing? If it helps, I can report the primary y-axis values